# How to cross-compile boost 1.58.0 from 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to win-64 using mingw?

Tags: boost, g++, ubuntu-16.04, mingw-w64

Accoring to other answers I called:

```
1) ./bootstrap.sh
2) echo "using gcc : : x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ ;" > user-config.jam
3) ./b2 --user-config=user-config.jam toolset=gcc-mingw target-os=windows release
4) ./bjam install toolset=gcc-mingw --prefix=/opt/boost
```

Everything seems fine until 4), where I get:

```
/home/salda/Downloads/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/tools/gcc.jam:121: in gcc.init from module gcc
error: toolset gcc initialization:
error: version 'mingw' requested but 'g++-mingw' not found and version '5.4.0' of default 'g++' does not match
error: initialized from
/home/salda/Downloads/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/build/toolset.jam:43: in toolset.using from module toolset
/home/salda/Downloads/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/build-system.jam:461: in process-explicit-toolset-requests from module build-system
/home/salda/Downloads/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/build-system.jam:527: in load from module build-system
/home/salda/Downloads/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/kernel/modules.jam:289: in import from module modules
/home/salda/Downloads/boost_1_58_0/tools/build/src/kernel/bootstrap.jam:139: in boost-build from module
/home/salda/Downloads/boost_1_58_0/boost-build.jam:17: in module scope from module
```

I have about 10 similar questions open in tabs, but I not able to fix it and finish the installation :(

Comment: Maybe unify g++/gcc to use only 1 of it? I don't know.

Comment: When I omitted the last "toolset=gcc-mingw", it somehow works.

Comment: It didn't create any folder :(

Comment: So it needed sudo on the start of the 4th row.

Answer (score 0):

So I think the correct way is to call:

```
1) ./bootstrap.sh
2) echo "using gcc : : x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ ;" > user-config.jam
3) ./b2 --user-config=user-config.jam toolset=gcc-mingw target-os=windows release
4) sudo ./bjam install --prefix=/opt/boost
```